# Limiting the amount of information printed by Perl debugger

Tags: perl, debugging

One of my pet peeves with debugging Perl code (in command line debbugger, `perl -d`) is the fact that mistakenly printing (via `x` command) the contents of a huge datastructure is guaranteed to freeze up your terminal for forever and a half while 100s of pages of data are printed. Epecially if that happens across slowish network.

As such, I'd like to be able to limit the amount of data that `x` prints.

I see two approaches - I'd be willing to try either if someone knows how to do.

1. Limit the amount of data any single command in debugger prints.
2. Better yet, somehow replace the built-in `x` command with a custom Perl method (which would calculate the "size" of the data structure, and refuse to print its contents without confirmation).

I'm specifically asking "how to replace `x` with custom code" - building a Good Enough "is the data structure too big" Perl method is something I can likely do on my own without too much effort although I see enough pitfalls preventing the "perfect" one from being a fairly frustrating endeavour. Heck, merely doing Data::Dumper->Dump and taking the length of the string might do the trick :)

Please note that I'm perfectly well aware of how to manually avoid the issue by recursively examining layers of datastructure (e.g. print the ref, print the count of keys/array elements, etc...)... the whole point is I want to be able to avoid thoughtlessly typing `x $huge_pile_of_data` without thinking - or stumbling on a bug populating said huge pile of data into what should be a scalar.

Comment: I often use the simple approach mentioned in your question, adding this subroutine to code I'm debugging: `sub xx { use Data::Dumper; print Dumper(@_) }`. Then I use `xx $foo` within the debugger rather than `x $foo`. As you say, a person could make `xx()` more full-service by checking length before printing.

Comment: @FM - but this presumes you have the foresight of knowing $foo is big. My whole problem is doing this by accident.

Comment: What I'm suggesting does not require that you presume anything about `$foo`. Rather, it requires a change in habit: use `xx` all the time, rather than `x` -- mainly because the output of `Data::Dumper` is nicer than the output of `x`, but also because using your own dumping subroutine makes it easy to customize behavior as needed by the problem at hand. Just an idea, of course.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `|` command in the debugger pipes another command's output to your pager, *e.g.*

```
  DB<1> |x %huge_datastructure
```

Comment: Meaning: The advantage is that the huge output will be sent to the pager (like `less`), and you can instruct the pager to quit and to discard existing and future output of the `x %huge_datastructure` .

Answer (score 14):

The `x` command takes an optional argument for the maximum depth to display. That's not quite the same as limiting the amount of data to N pages, but it's definitely useful to prevent overload.

```
  DB<1> %h = (a => { b => { c => 1 } } )

  DB<2> x %h
0  'a'
1  HASH(0x1d5ff44)
   'b' => HASH(0x1d61424)
      'c' => 1

  DB<3> x 2 %h
0  'a'
1  HASH(0x1d5ff44)
   'b' => HASH(0x1d61424)
```

You can specify the default depth to print via the `o` command, e.g.

```
DB<1>o dumpDepth=1
```

Add that to your `.perldb` file to apply it to all debugger sessions.

Otherwise, it looks like the `x` command invokes `DB::dumpit()` which is just a wrapper for `dumpval.pl` (or, more specifically, the `main::dumpValue()` sub it defines). You could modify/replace that script as you see fit. I'm not sure how you'd make it interactive, though.